# How to get the user's pinned sites?

Tags: support, api, users, sites

I have been trying to find the API for getting all the pinned/favorite sites of the user, but I can't.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, the newest version is site now. Please show m how to get them ?

Comment: @Glorfindel What do you mean " mobile app has that info " ? It also has on the web and when the 2.3 version will be  released?

Comment: Not everything that is available on the web is exposed via the API, probably less than half of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is not available in the officially released version of the API (2.2) and you won't find it in the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/).

However, the Stack Exchange mobile apps have some 'special' API methods, hosted under https://mobile.stackexchange.com, which do expose this information. That's why you're able to see (and maintain) this list from the apps. They are [no longer in development](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/295232) but still work.

I just tried a `GET` call to the following URL: https://mobile.stackexchange.com/1/preferences/get-pinned-sites?filter=fLdr8Pr0.&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&key=[APPLICATION_KEY] and got the following result:

```
[
  {"site":{"api_site_parameter":"meta"},"position":0},
  {"site":{"api_site_parameter":"boardgames"},"position":1},
  {"site":{"api_site_parameter":"puzzling"},"position":2}
  ...
]
```

which is indeed the list of [my currently pinned sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X3kU.png). However, this method **only** works if you use an access token and key of one of the **official Stack Exchange mobile apps**, which you can discover with a tool like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/). That means you can basically forget about enabling this functionality for an arbitrary user using your app.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I hope it will available soon in the next release